# separate Wordpress content; put it into two separate divs

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to separate out the different parts of my wordpress posts (at this point specifically the blockquote) so I can put them in different divs so I can put them on different parts of the page.

I have been able to remove the blockqoute and post the content without it, but couldn't put it back in

```
<div1>
<?php add_filter( 'the_content', 'rm_quotes' );
        function rm_quotes($content) {
          $content = preg_replace("~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~", "", $content);

          return $content; 
        }
?>
</div1>

<div2>
  <!-- This is where I want to put the <blockquote> -->
</div2>
```

Comment: You could try to use global variables like here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136402/save-something-to-global-var-in-add-filter

Answer (score 0):

Do a `preg_match` and put it into a variable called $quotes and then remove it from content with preg_replace. Now you can do whatever you want with the blockquotes that were removed.

example code:

```
preg_match('/<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>/', $content, $quotes);
var_dump($quotes);
```

Comment: You can put it right after the function before the preg_replace.

Comment: Tried and it throws a - Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'b'

Comment: Please escape the brackets.